# Using local images in WPF preview of Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#Local_Images) documentation, it is possible to reference a local image with the same file name across different platforms in shared Xamarin Forms code.

There are instructions on where the image files should be located and what the build action should be set to for iOS, Android, Windows Phone and UWP projects.

Unfortunately, instructions are missing for the recently released [WPF preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF) of Xamarin Forms.

Where should the local image files be placed, and what should the build action be set to in a WPF Xamarin Forms project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a build action of `Content` for your images, *assumably* in the `Assets` folder

[image]

FYI: There are 3 registered WPF image sources in Forms

1. `FileImageSourceHandler`
2. `StreamImageSourceHandler`
3. `UriImageSourceHandler`

[Forms WPF Image Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF/Renderers/ImageRenderer.cs#L120)

Additional Info from @AndersGustafsson

1. *Build Action* **Content** is the same build action as for Windows Phone and UWP platforms.
2. It seems like you are required to copy the image file to the output directory for the image to be recognized by the WPF application. This is different from UWP, where copying is not required.
3. It is OK to add the image file as a link in the WPF project. If I am not mistaken, this is not allowed in UWP.

Comment: Typical :-) For some stupid reason I only tried build actions *Resource* (which was assigned by default) and *None*, with copy to output directory. Your response solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AndersGustafsson no problem, glad to help.

Comment: Do you think you could add a few things to your answer for further clarification? 

First, *Build Action* **Content** is the same build action as for Windows Phone and UWP platforms, it might be good to point out this commonality. 

Second, it seems like you are required to copy the image file to the output directory for the image to be recognized by the WPF application. This is different from UWP, where copying is not required.

Third, it is OK to add the image file *as a link* in the WPF project. If I am not mistaken, this is not allowed in UWP.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Thanks, done, feel free to edit it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for adding, I have made some minor modifications now.

Comment: In my case, I had to put the image at the project's root (not inside the 'assets' folder).